# How to extend the functionality of an Entity that can't be modified?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

I'm working with Symfony 3.3 and I want to add a function to a Class that implements an Entity:

```
/**
 * GeoName
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="geo__name" ,indexes={
 *     @ORM\Index(name="geoname_geoname_search_idx", columns={"name", "country_code"})
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Bordeux\Bundle\GeoNameBundle\Repository\GeoNameRepository")
 */
class GeoName
{
    ...
}
```

So I extended that class and added the desired function.

```
use ...\GeoName as BaseEntity;

class GeoName extends BaseEntity
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

### Errors

If I don't use annotations at all, when I use the subclass the system doesn't recognise it as an Entity:

```
Class "GeoNameBundle\Entity\GeoName" sub class of "Bordeux\Bundle\GeoNameBundle\Entity\GeoName" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

If I declare my subclass as an Entity with annotations `@ORM\Entity`, when I use it the system expects two tables, because it takes my extension as a Class Model inheritance (not properly defined):

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t1.id AS id_2, t1.name AS name_3, ...[MORE FIELDS]... FROM geo__name t1 WHERE t0.id = ?' with params [6362055]:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.id' in 'where clause'
```

What can I do if **I can't edit the annotations or any content of the superclass** (because it's a library) and taking in consideration that **I'm not really trying to implement a Model Inheritance**, only adding a function to the Class implementing an Entity.

Thank you for your attention and help.

Answer (score 0):

Annotation should be copied to the extended class:

```
use ...\GeoName as BaseEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="geo__name" ,indexes={
 *     @ORM\Index(name="geoname_geoname_search_idx", columns={"name", "country_code"})
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Bordeux\Bundle\GeoNameBundle\Repository\GeoNameRepository")
 */
class GeoName extends BaseEntity
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```